# C# Event Handling involving publisher subscriber not working

Tags: c#, event-handling, custom-events

I have a publisher class and a subscriber class. The publisher class has an event and the subscriber wants to execute one of its own methods when this event is raised.

Here is my publisher class with its event:

```
public delegate EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args);
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Content { set; get; }
}

public class Publisher
{
    public event MyEventHandler MyCustomEvent;

    public void TriggerEvent()
    {
        if(MyCustomEvent!=null)
            MyCustomEvent(this, new MyEventArgs{ Content = "Geeee! This isn't working!" });
    }
}
```

And here is the subscriber:

```
class Subscriber
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();

        //hook the event to a method
        publisher.MyCustomEvent += (s, e) => delegate
        {
            PrintThis(e.Content);
        };

       //Do something to trigger the event    
        publisher.TriggerEvent();
    }
    static public void PrintThis(string content)
    {
        Console.Write(content);
    }
}
```

The publisher should not be aware of the subscriber. I want the subscriber to be able to execute its PrintThis function when the publisher invokes the event. But this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The breakpoint at PrintThis function is never hit. Nothing is printed on the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined the event handler properly.

Do it like this:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args);
```

Notice that the return type is `void`.

And then the event handler itself should be:

```
    publisher.MyCustomEvent += (s, e) =>
    {
        PrintThis(e.Content);
    };
```

Also your `TriggerEvent` method is safer if defined this way:

```
public void TriggerEvent()
{
    var mce = MyCustomEvent;
    if (mce!=null)
    {
        mce(this, new MyEventArgs{ Content = "Geeee! This isn't working!" });
    }
}
```

In a multi-threaded environment the `MyCustomEvent` handler could change between the `null` check and the invocation.

Comment: Oh..That works! Thanks a ton :) What was the difference? I mean the compiler was not giving any syntactic error.

Comment: The compiler is quite lenient when it comes to casting from one delegate to another if you explicitly cast as `delegate` (which you did). If you took out the `delegate` keyword only you would have seen an error message.